# How to test em-mongo + Goliath?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, asynchronous, eventmachine, goliath

This below app saves some data to the db and I want to test that it saves properly.

```
require 'goliath'

class App < Goliath::API
  def response(env)
     db = EM::Mongo::Connection.new('localhost').db('hello')
     db.collection('coll').insert({'identifier => 1'})

    [204, {}, {}]
  end
end

require 'goliath/test_helper'    
Goliath.env = :test

describe App do
  include Goliath::TestHelper

  it do
    with_api(described_class) do
      get_request do |req|
        db = EM::Mongo::Connection.new('localhost').db('hello')
        db.collection('coll').first.callback do |rec|
          rec['identifier'].should == 100
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The above spec passes since reactor ends before `callback` returns. I thought about manually starting a reactor like:

```
EM.run do
  db = EM::Mongo::Connection.new('localhost').db('hello')
  db.collection('coll').first.callback do |rec|
    rec['identifier'].should == 100

    EM.stop
  end
end
```

Though I'm not sure if starting the reactor for every spec is good practice. Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when the get_request is setup we add a callback on the request that stops the event loop. So, as soon as your block finishes (which will be before the connection is even created), it will stop the reactor.

I'm not sure the best solution, but a crappy one would be to override:

```
def hookup_request_callbacks(req, errback, &blk)
  req.callback &blk
  req.callback { stop }

  req.errback &errback if errback
  req.errback { stop }
end
```

in your test class after you include Goliath::TestHelper. Then, I think, you should be able to write your own that just has something like:

```
def hookup_request_callbacks(req, errback, &blk)
  req.callback &blk

  req.errback &errback if errback
  req.errback { stop }
end
```

You'll just have to make sure you call stop in your callback from Mongo.

I haven't actually tested this, so let me know if something doesn't work and I can dig in further.

Comment: That does work, thx! On an unrelated note, learned a whole lot from your blog, thx!

Answer (score 0):

@dj2's solution works great, but I decided instead of use `mongo` gem in specs, instead of `em-mongo`. Since `mongo` blocks, I don't have to worry about Goliath stopping the reactor before database returns results.

Comment: if you are using 'mongo' (which blocks) now, wouldn't you be giving up on a lot of EventMachine's promises (i.e., super-high scalability due to asynchronous reactor pattern)?

Comment: I'm using regular mongo only in specs. The reason was before random specs would fail without any reason, probably because the assertions run before commands to database would complete.